# Change the resetpassword url host in meteor

Tags: meteor

I want to change the reset-password email template url

I want to change

```
localhost:3000/reset-password/dP8cuMPE220mEPA7l0uSRIq4
```

to

```
app.mysite.com/reset-password/dP8cuMPE220mEPA7l0uSRIq4
```

I've done this

```
  Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text = function(user, url) {
        url = url.replace('#/', '');
        url = url.replace('localhost:3000', 'app.mysite.com');
        return "Click this link to reset your password: " + url;
      };
```

This works on my localenvironment but when in production it doesn't have `localhost:3000`

so the url will not change

I want to change the host, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `ROOT_URL` environment parameter. Meteor will use it to generate this link. So if you set `ROOT_URL="http://app.myside.com/`, then the generated url will be `http://app.mysite.com/reset-password/blahBLAH`.

Comment: yeah, `Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function (token) {
      return 'http://app.myapp.com/reset-password/' + token;
  };` this also worked